# get title tag value using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, scrape

i want to get the value of the `<title>` tag for all the pages of my website. i am trying to run the script only on my website domain, and get all the pages links on my website , and the titles of them.

This is my code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://xxxxxxxxx.com');
//Create a new DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument;

//Parse the HTML. The @ is used to suppress any parsing errors
//that will be thrown if the $html string isn't valid XHTML.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

//Get all links. You could also use any other tag name here,
//like 'img' or 'table', to extract other tags.
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
foreach ($links as $link){
    //Extract and show the "href" attribute.
         echo $link->nodeValue;
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
}
```

What i get is: `<a href="z1.html">z2</a>` i get `z1.html` and `z2`....
my `z1.html` have a `title` named `z3`. i want to get `z1.html` and `z3`, not `z2`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use the same script on `z1.html` and replace `a` with `title`?

Comment: @jeroen hi , i am trying to run the script only on my website domain , and get all the pages links on my website , and the titles of them

Comment: i'm not understanding, but with your script you will get the text of the any <a> in the page, not the title. If you want to get the TITLE value you've to use $dom->getElementsByTagName("title").

Comment: I think he want all the list of anchor tag along with title

Comment: @MikhaMatta : do you only title or list of anchor tag ? your question is little confusing ? can you clarify.

Comment: @hitesh and the others, hi,i need a script...i put the domain or website link , i got EVERY page on the website (not only on home page ) and get the link as a text, for example: h t t p://zzzz.com/contactus.php and " Contact Us Page Title"....but for all the pages on the website !

Comment: so you dont need title?

Answer (score 2):

adding a bit to hitesh's answer to check if the elements have attributes and the desired attribute exists.  also if the getting the 'title' elements actually does return at least one item before trying to grab the first one ($a_html_title->item(0)).

and added an option for curl to follow location (needed it for my hardcoded test for google.com)

```
foreach ($links as $link) {

    //Extract and show the "href" attribute.
    if ($link->hasAttributes()){
        if ($link->hasAttribute('href')){

            $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
            $href = 'http://google.com';   // hardcoding just for testing

            echo $link->nodeValue;
            echo "<br/>".'MY ANCHOR LINK : - ' . $href . "---TITLE--->";
            $a_html = my_curl_function($href);

            $a_doc = new DOMDocument();
            @$a_doc->loadHTML($a_html);
            $a_html_title = $a_doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

            //get and display what you need:
            if ($a_html_title->length){
                $a_html_title = $a_html_title->item(0)->nodeValue;
                echo $a_html_title;
                echo '<br/>';
            }

        }
    }

}

function my_curl_function($url) {
    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'name');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);    // added this
    $html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your own custom function and call it in appropriate places , if you need to get multiple tags from the pages which are in anchor tag, you just need to create new custom function.

Below code will help you get started

```
$html = my_curl_function('http://www.anchorartspace.org/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$mytag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
//get and display what you need:
$title = $mytag->item(0)->nodeValue;

$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
foreach ($links as $link) {

//Extract and show the "href" attribute.
    echo $link->nodeValue;
    echo "<br/>".'MY ANCHOR LINK : - ' . $link->getAttribute('href') . "---TITLE--->";

    $a_html = my_curl_function($link->getAttribute('href'));
    $a_doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$a_doc->loadHTML($a_html);
    $a_html_title = $a_doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
//get and display what you need:
    $a_html_title = $a_html_title->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $a_html_title;
    echo '<br/>';
}
echo "Title: $title" . '<br/><br/>';

function my_curl_function($url) {
    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'name');
    $html = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    return $html;
}
```

let me know if you need any more help

Comment: put ur website name in the url and see whether it solves the issue you are facing

Comment: mmm u got some errors for php...like the } here:  echo "<br/>"; } echo "Title: $title" . '<br/><br/>';